# How to use contract address in web3js dynamicly with hardhat?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, truffle-deployment

I have an contract but when I deploy with hardhat in artifact json code there s no contract address property but with truffle there was. I wanna use hardhat and use contract address not staticly meaning not hard coding it but dont know how to get it. Anyone know that about hardhat?